# How to set 5.1 surround in the Sound Settings?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, settings, headset

I have a logitech G35 headset which should allow even up to 7.1 dolby surround but the sound settings identify it as a stereo only device. I configured the `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` by setting the default channels to 6 and searched for many other solutions, but I have not found any working solutions.

Comment: Is the USB headset the only device you have? IIRC, PulseAudio will show up as the default ALSA device, while you probably also have the actual devices available through alsa. In `alsamixer`, hit F6: this should pop up a list of devices: the "default" entry, plus one entry for each device. Use the up and down arrows to pick another device and ENTER/Return to select the highlighed device. If this shows your headset *and* your headset shows up with stereo channels, then it's being correctly detected and configured, and the issue is probably with enabling surround in pulseaudio.

Comment: @njsq

It does show up in the alsamixer with the stereo channels. If the problem is due to pulseaudio is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Old I know, but I have a G35 also and as far as I know there are only two real speakers. The surround sound effect is entirely virtual, synthesized in the Windows software.

Comment: http://blog.logitech.com/2009/05/06/logitech-g35-headset-under-the-hood/

Comment: Although there are comments this year (2017) the OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years and appears to have abandoned this question about an EOL Ubuntu version. As such VTC as `not reproducible`.